# When does compiler not generate move constructor and move assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11

In Effective Modern C++, it said

> Move operations are generated only for classes lacking explicitly
>   declared move operations, copy operations, and a destructor.

But I tested it with Gcc and Clang, no error was thrown out. So is this rule out of date?

[Example program](https://godbolt.org/g/Ac6YPJ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A
{
    int i;
    public:
    ~A() = default;
};

int main()
{
    A a, b;
    a = b;
    A c(a);
    A d(std::move(a));
    b = std::move(d);
}
```

Edit: copied "move operations" from the book which might lead to confusion. Changed it to move constructor and move assignment.

Comment: Let's start with the basic. What is a *move operation*?

Comment: The compiler generates them when the language says it should, unless it is buggy.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't move, just like `std::forward` doesn't forward, `std::remove` doesn't remove and `delete` doesn't delete its operand :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl - Also known as "best names, ever"

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yeah, well, it's just that `std::prepare_for_move`, `std::prepare_for_forward`, `std::shuffle_around_in_order_to_remove` and `delete_object_pointed_to_by` would be even worse :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl - I personally am in favor of `std::as_xvalue`. Would mean that more programmers will have to be familiar with the value categories. In my book it's good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::move` is just a cast to a `A&&`. The very same xvalue it creates will happily bind to a `const A&`, which is what the the implicitly defaulted copy c'tor and copy assignment operator accept. So that's what you are calling.

The fact you "appear" to `std:move` doesn't mean any of those move operations is defined.

If you add a `A(A&) = default;` to your class, things will start being underlined in red. Because now the copy c'tor accepts a non-const lvalue reference, that will not bind to a `A&&`.

Comment: "Underlined in red?"  I guess that depends on your compilation-mode settings, and your terminal.  Usually, GCC doesn't decorate its error messages thus (perhaps Clang does?)

Comment: @TobySpeight - It was a reference to the OP's godbolt link.