# compiler defined move constructor with destructor

Tags: c++, move-constructor

As per the cpp reference [cpp-ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), compiler does not generate a default move constructor if we have a user defined destructor.

Code snippet:

```
 class General
{
public:
    ~General();
    General();
    void testInitList();
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    General b(std::move(General()));
    General g = std::move(b);
    g.testInitList();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles implying that the compiler generated a default move constructor. The code was compiled using gcc version 5.4.0.

Could someone explain why the compiler generated a move constructor and move assignment operator in this case despite have a destructor?

Best,
Rahul

Comment: First, it compiled. Second, i had print statements in constructor and destructor. Only one constructor statement was printed where as multiple destructor statements  were printed.

Comment: You don't define a copy constructor, that's why you don't have enough printings.

Comment: hmm. Okay let me try.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does compiler not generate move constructor and move assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818755/when-does-compiler-not-generate-move-constructor-and-move-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's no move constructor or assignment operator, no move is performed. [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) doesn't perform the move. It just casts its argument to indicate that a move *may* be performed *if* possible. If not possible, then there's no move and using `std::move` does nothing.

Comment: I had print statements in constructor and destructor. Only one constructor statement was printed where as multiple destructor statements were printed. It implies that the object was indeed moved. Output - Creating General 
Destroying General 
Destroying General 
Destroying General

Comment: Understood where I was making the mistake. Thank you so much Nikos.

Comment: @RGs Your code calls the default constructor and the implicitly defined copy constructor. So yes, only one will be printed. Define a copy constructor and print something there.